# Admob not showing ad in a layout with listview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, google-analytics

My ad isn't showing when I put the adview within a layout that contains a listview. Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </ListView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1596992408570157/3380743224" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I get this LogCat error message: "Not enough space for ad. Needs 960 X 150 pixels, but only has 1080 X 75 pixels."

I tried placing the ad before the listview and that works, but that's not how I want it.

Comment: Okay, I managed to  solve the issue by changing the layout_height of the listview to wrap_content although that sparked another problem. My ad now has about 5 pixels of margin space on the right and left and about 15 pixels of margin space from the bottom. How do I fix that?

Comment: I've fixed it. I changed my layout to a relative layout and I used android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for the ad and changed the banner to a SMART_BANNER.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` height is taking up the entire space of the parent.

Try replacing your `ListView` with the following:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```